# Call component on external url without changing that url

Tags: angular

I have an external url. E.g. http://www.google.com

Now what I have to do is, when this url hits on browser, then accroding to url, my angular component should call, but url should not change.

Comment: Did you try anything? share with us so we can try to help.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I am not sure how you can handle external url call triggering route change inside angular.

That aside, For skipping url change in browser, Assume the below is your routerlink:

`<a [routerLink] = "["/external/url", {skipLocationChange: true}]"></a>`. you can use skipLocationChange property of routerLink to skip the url change.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to give more details, But according to my assumption you can try below solution:

You need to import `DOCUMENT` from `@angular/platform-browser` or `@angular/common` in Angular and you can use `document.location.href` to open external url.

```
document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

If you want to use the above code in a function:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }
redirect(): void {
    this.document.location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
}
```

**In html:**

```
<button type="button" (click)="redirect()">Redirect to Google</button>
```

Comment: thanks, but its not my requirement. Its fine when I want to move on any external url from my component. But my condition is reverse, I want to call component on click of external url with using queryParams of that url.